# Running an application, better to load resources or store them to use?

Tags: java

My question is somewhat related to this question ([Better to load resources on the run or to pre load them on memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596117/better-to-load-resources-on-the-run-or-to-pre-load-them-on-memory)) however I have some of my own thoughts to bring to the table.

Namely, I understand loading resources on the fly can have performance repercussions (delays in loading, lag, etc), however I guess the real question is it better to pre-load everything needed or is it better to load as they are required.

For example: I am currently working on a 2D game. On load of the game it automatically loads some of the required images/sprites. However I was thinking of expanding this to also include the maps, items, and npcs (which are currently saved in text files). That being said, the latency for loading maps is fairly noticeable (0.5 - 1.25 seconds when changing maps in-game). The NPC's and Items are of little consequence (since they are generally small, and there will be a small number of them).

Would this be a better practice to load everything on start up of the program, or is it considered a bad practice? Likewise, if its only good for smaller implementations, when do you expect it would start to be a drain to the computer to have them all loaded? Please note I expect the game to contain around 200-500 maps, each of about 50kb in size maximum, and the items to be less then 200kb total for all NPC's/Items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question.  This is how i solved it.

I went with both.  I created waypoints in my video game.  Each waypoint had various files that must be loaded by that waypoint.  Then I have a file loader that had a prioritized list of waypoints it needed to load files for.  Each waypoint had the files that it required.  In my game, when it reached a waypoint that was not finished loading (the file loader would track what percentage of the waypoint was complete) it would throw up the loading bar with the percentage.

The fileloader ran on a separate thread.  After implementing it I noticed that i only got one quick load bar at the beginning, which just loaded a bunch of menu images for the first menu, and I never see another loading bar again.  All the files get loaded by the time the user gets to the point where they need them.

EDIT:  I do not load a map's backgorund image until it is needed.  Though all the other units in that map, which are shared across other levels of the game, were already loaded.  There is a balance here between how much memory you willing to use up on the user's computer that would never be needed and loading time dleays you willing to subject the user to.  I was able to limit my memory footprint to about 150MB.  This gives me room to load all the maps should I decide to load the map's backgorund images if I want to.  If the game is a small casual game and you mem footprint is already at 400MB, then I would consider refraining from loading unnecessary objects.  The leaner you are with mem utilization, the more options you have for loading objects that may not be needed in effort to reduce loading times.

Comment: I was considering something similar, basically breaking my game up into content areas (e.g. maps 1-60 are all in a small contained area, so load them. Have a loading screen when they swap to a different area). It would optimize the memory usage slightly at least.